# Android onNotification never called in react-native-push-notification

Tags: push-notification, react-native, jsx, react-native-push-notification

```js
 PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: function(notification) {
      console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification);
},
})
```

notification received **form the server** when i clicked on it app is opened but **onNotification never called.**
i put this in **componentDidMount() and constructor in App.js** but it's never called..
help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the required code into the AndroidManifest.xml?

For example :

```xml
<!--more stuff above-->
<service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
  android:exported="false" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Source: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: switch to react-native-firebase ..solved all problem

Comment: @3iL moved to the react-native-firebase from react-native-push-notification.in react-native-firebase you will get all logs when notification arrived in background/foreground